# How to control the streambuilder when to receive new documents in firebase?

Tags: flutter

We're working on a social media like application and using firebase as a database. Now every time some user create a post and the system upload it to database the stream builder automatically updating the list view, this cause an unwanted scroll down every time some user posts in the database

Our code looks like this

```
-Scaffold
  -Stream builder (where the post getting fetch individually)
   -Stack
   -List view (where we show all the posts from all users in the database)
```

[image: Our application looks like this]

Answer (score 0):

- If you do not want to receive live updates, then switch from a `StreamBuilder` to a `FutureBuilder`. This one will query the data only once until you re-build.
- If you wanted to keep the live updates , but want to avoid the "unwanted" scroll, then perhaps you need to "sort" your documents in a way that will avoid the scroll (e.g. show older documents first)